# TypeScript: How to omit second argument in function depending on the first argument

Tags: typescript, types

I want not to have a second argument in function depending on the what first argument function returns. I can set that its type is `undefined` but I still need to pass second argument. [Sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwAqygW2QHgBUA+eAbwCh54AHGASwDcoAXBarXALngIG5yAvuXJ0AdqxgAzKGAQARFlDKV4Ae1EhuyZvVEBzflWYB3VdwpUjACzib423QZVVJqgK4xumGDnyl42KpwWjpievACRIYR-ELkzACe1AgAsgkAYm6iYMx06vAAvPCERAAUKnrcpcDcCsxQAJSFJAQANCqwesjcBPAgAB6sosBo3r54YpIgMPAAgjBdJAD8cwto3FmgkmIgwORNBS19gyDDoxx+kfArDmHwPcdDI-ah+tc89-BZANaiqsaifjkCAgZgBSSFeClUoHEikARNFDwNKZbK5dT8EFgpRFbCSUrUZo0AB06hADV48AA9FTjskcvA-mDmKp4FYoAwEMhwOpgPBOuQmDMAEaQvEEonUYkmVQU6m00V0NA-P4AqFgIJwBmqhqC2DwUW4-GEw4kmXE1weVpkAJBOwAcigI3tETlNPsPOG-IWbKRACJAnA-TQYKpkjBEkA)

```
declare class Params<T> {
  private params: T;
}

interface Data {
  one: string;
  two: {
    three: string;
    four: Params<{ more: string }>;
  };
}

type MyFunction = <T>(
  g: (d: Data) => T,
  args: T extends Params<infer Args> ? Args : undefined
) => T extends Params<{}> ? string : T extends string ? T : unknown;

let mf = (() => {}) as MyFunction;
let a = mf(p => p.one); // expect not to have second arg
var b = mf(p => p.two); // b is unknown (correct now)
var b = mf(p => p.two.four,); // second arg has "more" property
```

Also there is an issue that in example `b` I have a tooltip that I can pass second argument but when I do it TS shows error.
[image: TS Error]
And when I provide the argument it shows the error
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the function to take either one or two parameters depending on a generic type, you could use [rest parameters as tuples](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to express this.  Like this:

```
type MyFunction = <T>(
  g: (d: Data) => T,
  ...args: T extends Params<infer Args> ? [Args] : []
) => T extends Params<{}> ? string : T extends string ? T : unknown;
```

That's similar to what you had, except that now `args` is a rest parameter, and it's either one or zero elements long depending on what `T` is.  Now this works:

```
let mf = (() => {}) as MyFunction;
let a = mf(p => p.one);
var b = mf(p => p.two);
var c = mf((p: Data) => p.two.four, { more: "ads" });
```

But note that for `c` I had to explicitly annotate `p` as `Data`.  Without it, the compiler gets confused and infers `any`, and then `{more: "ads"}` is an error (because it couldn't tell that `p.two.four` was of a `Params<>` type.

---

What I'd probably do instead, though, is use [overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) to distinguish the two quite different ways of calling this function:

```
type MyFunction = {
  <A>(g: (d: Data) => Params<A>, args: A): string;
  <T>(g: (d: Data) => T): T extends string ? T : unknown;
};
```

That's a lot less type manipulation (and cuts out most of your conditional types) and now the compiler really knows what to expect:

```
let mf = ((() => {}) as any) as MyFunction;
let a = mf(p => p.one);
var b = mf(p => p.two);
var c = mf(p => p.two.four, { more: "ads" });
```

All of that works perfectly.  Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEAlaAXAKgVxgG2QG8AoJJePEKKJABRACdwoAeTAPiRLLJgYEsAbiHTI4TMFACEALiSYA3KSQBfYsv7BRDAGYJkAEREguysgHtgEOVHQDgAcyU8k6AO7m53F64AWDCGskW3snMx4dc2wGOXoJVkIkMHMAmztNB1V2Zx4VHLVldABPGGQAWSKAMWxgeHR+SyQAXiQ2dgAKcIc5doATOSN0EABKZs5MABpwgDpZxgcoOUwkCAAPUWBemjjmFk0dCAYkAEEGBc4AfiQAbVOFgF0kOWv75VGm8ZX1iE3txl3CCpLsF0o4nvIvhstiDQkgrss5DUANbAcxuYBKZQEdBJHTNJDtdrvTiA0ZUJAVaq1eqWHLYpAmFpgHTtGBjJAwaaWCDDHLCI4AI3xzNZ7M57nMvOU-PIwpZrIGxmJHOmEumkWiEy4SRSQQARCAtnrVFK1KBILB9EgAPKCQ54cyGmjeChUP7xNqmFx8IQiMT-SSyeT5dRkTTaPSIJCDEzeCxWNKhHJkCVecIp-yBRMZZMRKIxOgBhI61IwjJZXN5ZQFFMlcpVGp1BrAfFx1rHDrdAn9aNK9k7SQsDta+aLE7DbOOXNtdpdvqKobKzATiFrKE0ELl+Hg5Go9H5OkQHHM-GEons0kMmggYBFMk0SmNmkYrFHhly0UfFXcqVkGVCpkWTZL9xQ8X8kBleAP2AzhQPMdV8y1RJklLA0jRNJQ1CAA)